# Meaning of word "しんネタ"

Tags: meaning

Can't translate this sentence:

> しんネタ どらにゃんこを マスター！

Can be also たね (kana reversed).

Context:

[image: enter link description here]

Comment: I don't see the words in your linked meme. Are you sure it is the correct meme?

Comment: This is from game "Nyan Nyan Nyanko no Nyan Collection", i took text from there

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, ネタ is the 倒語/[anadrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anadrome) (reverse-ordered word) of 種{たね}/seed. It is usually used to refer to the source of a joke, comedy sketch, or an impersonation. しんネタ is 新ネタ, new ネタ.

I believe it is pretty common in the context of 漫才 where people talk about how a joke makes fun of a celebrity or a well-known event. You linked a meme in your question and in memes the idea is the same: the source or material for a joke.

どらにゃんこ is a play on [どら焼き](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%81%A9%E3%82%89%E7%84%BC%E3%81%8D).