# What does ネタ mean in 完全にネタだったから一日で変わったけど?

Tags: grammar, words

In this sentence here, I understand the overall gist of what it is saying, but I just can't find any sort of definition for ネタ. I'm thinking its some kind of slang which requires a bit of contextual knowledge of the word in order to understand it in this case:

> その前は『生きた心地がしない戦線』だったわ。完全にネタだったから一日で変わったけど

My guess is that it is expressing the speakers ridicule with the previous name of the group

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84540/30454

Comment: 元ネタ: https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/sss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relevant definitions of [ネタ](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AD%E3%81%9F/#jn-170158) here are

> ４ 演芸で上演する作品。また、その内容。芸の種類についてもいう。「落語の定番―」「歌―」
>
> ５ 人をかつぐための、真実めかした作り話。悪意のある嘘ではなく、相手を笑わせたり軽くからかったりする程度である場合をいう。「彼の失敗談は―だろう」

4 means *a piece of comedy (performance)* and 5 *a fake story for laughing*. The usage in question is mostly 5 even though it is not exactly a fake. A relevant phrase is お笑いのネタ,  literally meaning *a seed of laughing*

So you are basically right. It means *Formerly it was called .... The *ridiculous (joke)* name was changed in a day.*